# Why each state appears in at most one `GOTO` column in `LR` parsing table?

Tags: compiler-construction

I came across this excerpt from the *Compilers: Principles, Techniques and Tools* by *Ullman et. al.*

> There tend to be rather few states in any one column of the **`GOTO`** table.
>
> The reason is that the **`GOTO`** on nonterminal **`A`** can only be a state derivable from a set of items in which some items have **`A`** immediately to the left of a dot.
>
> **No set has items with `X` and `Y` immediately to the left of a dot if `X ≠ Y`. Thus, each state appears in at most one `GOTO` column.**

I could not understand their justification. Please help...

[image]

Is the reasoning something like this?

Comment: C'mon, this one's easy. The header of the column in the GOTO table is a non-terminal, right? And that non-terminal is the one which is being moved over to reach the new state. So it's the non-terminal which appears before the dot in the items which label that state. All of the items in a state have the same symbol before the dot, and that's the symbol which is the header of the GOTO table in which that state appears. (The same logic applies to shift actions in the action table: every state appears in only one column.)

Comment: In theory, that means you could delete the headers from the GOTO table, leaving only a mapping from current state to a list of possible successor states. You could then do the goto action by scanning through the possible successor states until you find one with the appropriate non-terminal before the dot in some item. It's hard to think of a reason to do this, but it would be possible.

Comment: If you don't understand why a state's itemset has the same symbol before all the dots, look at the way states are constructed. You select the initial items for a new state by choosing the items in the current state in which the dot is before the symbol you are working on, and then moving the dot past that symbol in all of those items. Then you use closure to fill in the rest of the items in the itemset, but all of the items created by closure have the dot at the beginning.

Comment: @rici, it seems very easy after you have explained it in such a vivid manner. Before the explanation, it was not that easy for me, but yes I had previously got a rough/crude idea after reading the text, but your explanation, made my understanding firm. Thanks a lot, once again. :)